# slick 3.2 - how to define an "abstract" trait with tables and queries definitions but no concrete profile?

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I want to define the queries and tables without the direct import of the final database profile (H2, MySQL etc) - so in unit tests I would use H2, and for the staging/production I would use MySQL. So far I couldn't find a way to import all necessary abstract components to get this working:

```
import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._

class OAuthCredentialsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[OAuth](tag, "credentials_oauth") {

  def username: Rep[String] = column[String]("username", O.SqlType("VARCHAR"))

  def service: Rep[String] = column[String]("service", O.SqlType("VARCHAR"))

  def serviceId: Rep[String] = column[String]("service_id", O.SqlType("VARCHAR"))

  def userRef: ForeignKeyQuery[UserTable, User] = foreignKey("oauth_user_fk", username, userTable)(_.username, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)

  override def * = (username, service, serviceId) <> (OAuth.tupled, OAuth.unapply)

}

val oauthTable: TableQuery[OAuthCredentialsTable] = TableQuery[OAuthCredentialsTable]
```

Answer (score 3):

Eventually I discovered that to accomplish the driver-agnostic setup, it could be done as simple as that:

```
object UserPersistence extends JdbcProfile {

  import api._

  class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
    def username: Rep[String] = column[String]("username", O.PrimaryKey, O.SqlType("VARCHAR"))

    def password: Rep[String] = column[String]("password", O.SqlType("VARCHAR"))

    def serverkey: Rep[String] = column[String]("serverkey", O.SqlType("VARCHAR"), O.Length(64))

    def salt: Rep[String] = column[String]("salt", O.SqlType("VARCHAR"), O.Length(64))

    def iterations: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("iterationcount", O.SqlType("INT"))

    def created: Rep[Timestamp] = column[Timestamp]("created_at", O.SqlType("TIMESTAMP"))

    val mkUser: ((String, String, String, String, Int, Timestamp)) ⇒ User = {
      case ((name, pwd, _, _, _, created)) ⇒ User(name, pwd, created.toInstant)
    }

    def unMkUser(u: User) = Some(u.username, u.password, "", "", 0, new Timestamp(u.createdAt.toEpochMilli))

    override def * = (username, password, serverkey, salt, iterations, created) <> (mkUser, unMkUser)
  }

  val userTable: TableQuery[UserTable] = TableQuery[UserTable]

}
```

and then in order to use different profiles - you need to supply different database implementation when you run something, e.g

```
trait UserPersistence {

  protected def db: Database

  protected implicit val ec: ExecutionContext

  override def findCredentialsOrRegister(oauthCredentials: OAuth): Future[User] = {

    val userFound = (for (
      creds ← oauthTable.filter(x ⇒ x.service === oauthCredentials.service && x.serviceId === oauthCredentials.serviceId);
      user ← userTable.filter(x ⇒ x.username === creds.username)
    ) yield user).result

    val authenticate = userFound.flatMap {
      case Seq(user) ⇒
        DBIO.from(Future.successful(user))
      case Seq() ⇒
        val newUUID = UUID.randomUUID
        val user = User(newUUID.toString, UUID.randomUUID().toString, Instant.now())
        DBIO.seq(
          userTable += user,
          oauthTable += oauthCredentials.copy(username = newUUID.toString)
        ) andThen DBIO.from(Future.successful(user))
    }

    db.run(authenticate.transactionally)
  }
```

and then in test

```
val impl = new UserPersistence {

  override def db: H2Profile.api.Database = // initialize and populate the database

  override implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global

}
```

For MySql just assign the MySQL profile to `db` property (and change type).

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got you right, you can achieve it with injections and your configuration, separating test config from prod,

So I think you can do something like this-

Create binding for injection-

```
class DbModule extends Module {
  bind[slick.driver.JdbcProfile#Backend#Database] toNonLazy DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](inject[Application]).db
}
```

Then (for example)-

```
abstract class BaseDaoImpl[T <: IdentifiableTable[S] : ClassTag, S <: RichEntity[S]](implicit injector: Injector)
  extends BaseDao[S] with Injectable with Logger{

  protected val db: slick.driver.JdbcProfile#Backend#Database = inject[slick.driver.JdbcProfile#Backend#Database]
  protected val table: TableQuery[T]


  def insert(obj: S): Future[S] = {
    val insertQuery = table.returning(table.map(_.id)) into ((item, id) => item.withDifferentId(Some(id)))
    val res = db.run(insertQuery += obj)
    logger.debug(s"Inserting ${this.getClass} - ${res.toString}")
    res
  }

  def all(): Future[Seq[S]] = {
    db.run(table.result)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this configuration in order to change the DB profile in a application.conf file.

```
import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile
import slick.basic._
trait DBComponent {
    // use the application.conf to change the profile  
    val database = DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile]("h2")  
    val driver = database.profile

}


trait BankTable extends DBComponent  {
    import driver.api._
    class BankTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Bank](tag, "bank") {
        val id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
        val name = column[String]("name")
        def * = (name, id.?) <> (Bank.tupled, Bank.unapply)

    }

    protected val bankTableQuery = TableQuery[BankTable]
    protected def bankTableAutoInc = bankTableQuery returning 
bankTableQuery.map(_.id)
}

class BankRepositoryBDImpl extends BankTable  with BankRepository  {
    import driver.api._
    val db = database.db
    def createBank(bank: Bank): Future[Int] = db.run { bankTableAutoInc += bank }
}
```

and use a application.conf file

```
h2 = {
url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test1"
driver = org.h2.Driver
connectionPool = disabled
keepAliveConnection = true
}

sqlite = {
url = "jdbc:sqlite::memory:"
driver = org.sqlite.JDBC
connectionPool = disabled
keepAliveConnection = true
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to check the Question's age when answering. This one didn't have an accepted answer and this may help people in the future, so otherwise it's good by me.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this in my project I created an object out of the `JdbcProfile` trait and imported that everywhere:

`JdbcProfile.scala`:

```scala
package my.application.data.support

import slick.jdbc.JdbcProfile

object JdbcProfile extends JdbcProfile
```

Wherever I define tables I import it as follows:

```scala
import my.application.data.support.JdbcProfile.api._
...
```

In order to support extensions to slick, I created an abstraction called `DatabaseSupport` where each database type would have their own concrete implementation which is injected at startup-time depending on configuration.

`DatabaseSupport.scala`:

```scala
package my.application.data.support

/**
  * Database support implicits and methods.
  */
trait DatabaseSupport {

  /**
    * Implicit database array type.
    */
  implicit val seqStringType: JdbcProfile.DriverJdbcType[Seq[String]]
}
```

This way I can have seperate `H2DatabaseSupport.scala` and `PostgresDatabaseSupport.scala` implementations that specifies `seqStringType` in database-specific ways.